# cannot work dropdown component in foundation 5

Tags: zurb-foundation

all. I'm new to foundation.
I tried to make a dropdown example, but it didn't work at all.

```css
--all.scss--
.test{
  #drop2{
    @include dropdown-container;
  }
}
```

```html
--test.html--
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta content='IE=edge,chrome=1' http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'>
    <title>test</title>
    <meta content='' name='description'>
    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0' name='viewport'>
    <link href='css/all.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="test">
      <a data-dropdown='drop2' href='#'>Has Content Dropdown</a>
      <div class='f-dropdown content' data-dropdown-content id='drop2'>
        <p>
          Some text that people will think is awesome!
          Some text that people will think is awesome!
          Some text that people will think is awesome!
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src='js/modernizr.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='js/jquery.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='js/fastclick.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='js/foundation.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='js/foundation.dropdown.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      $(document).foundation();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The browser shows the text "Has Content Dropdown", but nothing happens when I click the link.
I wonder that I must misunderstand how to use the dropdown component, but can't find what is wrong.
What's wrong with the program?   Please help.

foundation 5.4.6

using Middleman and sass

Comment: It looks like the code snippet does not include foundation.js or any js for that matter. You're also missing all of foundation's css.

Comment: I checked again the code and understood that the code didn't load foundation as you told.
Thanks!